# Serial port listener not return data (JSSC)

Tags: java, javafx, jssc

Hello I have the following code :

```
if(!serialPort.isOpened()) {
                // ouverture du port
                serialPort.openPort();

                System.out.println("JSSC -> initPort() : Ouverture du port");

                //config billet
                serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_7, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_EVEN);

                // on crée une ecoute sur le port pour recuperer la reponse
                serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialPortEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {

                        if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0) {
                            try {
                                    String dataReceived = serialPort.readHexString(event.getEventValue());
                                    System.out.println("JSSC -> initPort() : Received response hexstring: " + dataReceived);
                                    CashSorterSend.getInstance().renvoyerReponse(dataReceived);
                                    System.out.println("----------------------------------");
                            }
                            catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                                System.out.println("JSSC -> initPort() : Error in receiving string from COM-port: " + ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

The Serial Port send data answer if I send one message when I click on a Button.
But Me, I would like repeat indefiny an message, with the following code :

```
// on declare la tache de fond qui interrogera la compteuse a billet
    taskDetailBillets = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            while (true) {

                Thread.sleep(300);
                CashSorterSend.getInstance().detailBillets();
            }
        }
    };

    // on demarre notre thread
    threadDetailBillets = new Thread(taskDetailBillets);
    threadDetailBillets.start();
```

And the following class :

```
public class DetailBillets implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("DetailBillets -> run() : Thread DetailBillets");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(600);
        JSSC.getInstance().sendMessage(Constants.COMMAND_HEXA_BILLET_DETAILS, true);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

My probleme is that the port not send answer... Messages are send infinitly in the thread but the port not send answer... It's so speed the send in a thread to the port answer ??
How looped send messages ?

Thanks and sorry for mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `while(true)`, you could put the code within a `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);`

Currently, I'm looking at the code and I am wondering how's the `DetailBillets` Runnable is being fired.

Is `JSSC.getInstance()` a singleton which references the same instance of `serialPort` used in you first code block ? What's the implementation of `sendMessage` ? Is it using the writeString method of `SerialPort` ?

Maybe specify a `flowControlMode` on your `serialPort` instance ? In my case: `SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN | SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_OUT`